# uWSGI fastrouter/subscription, Nginx and public facing servers

Tags: uwsgi

I'm having some security issues regarding my uWSGI configuration.

**Here's the current issue:**

I have a front server, called **api.domain.tld**, that have NGinx installed with `proxy_pass` that points to the uWSGI instance using a `.sock` file.

This uWSGI instance on the frontend server is configured that way:

```
uwsgi -M --fastrouter /tmp/project.sock --fastrouter-subscription-server public_ip:port
```

And, as you might expect, I have a fleet of servers that contains the actual code and runs uWSGI that subscribe to this fastrouter, like this:

```
uwsgi --socket public_ip_of_sub_server:port -M --subscribe-to ip_front_lb:port:api.domain.tld
```

(with other params).

**Here's my problem:**

All the server are publicly available, not a part of a private network (The servers I took comes from different offers and doesn't offer this possibility, unfortunately).

For the frontend, that means YOU can plug your uWSGI instance to it ... not great.
I've found out that I can [secure the subscription system](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SubscriptionServer.html#securing-the-subscription-system), so this should be ok (can you confirm or infirm it?).

But now, the `socket` parameter on the sub_servers is public, [which is discouraged by uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html#things-to-know-best-practices-and-issues-read-it) (first point).

**So my question:**

How can I take advantage of `fastrouter`/`subscription` from uWSGI on servers that are facing public access while keeping things secure?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use a firewall.

Comment: Do you think it's secure enough if i implement the secure system for the load balancer but keeping it open (for new sub-servers to register), and implement a one way firewall on the sub-servers?